# Gibbs entropy and Shannon entropy

Tags: terminology, entropy, history, information-theory

The two formulations seem identical to me:
$H(x) = \sum p(x) \log(1/p(x));$
why would the equation be attributed to Shannon rather than Gibbs (in the context of information)?

Comment: Shannon's entropy is log base $2$, whereas Gibb's entropy is log base $e$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that in the context of statistics the two mean the same thing (apart perhaps from the conventions, like the base of the logarithm, as noted in the comments.) Different names exist, because in physics these are not the same, although they are often confused.

See for discussion [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/720009/247642) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/709656/247642).